# Literary criticism term for character espousing author's ideas?

Tags: characters

Is there a term in literary criticism for a character who espouses the points of view of the author? Especially, but not necessarily, if that character has no other role in the work. (This is different from a "Mary Sue".)

Comment: This is sooo sad...Lit SE going down and all the migrateable things coming to us. :(

Comment: TVTropes uses the term [Author Filibuster](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AuthorFilibuster).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *[mouthpiece](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=noTRMjASamEC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=literary%20terms%20mouthpiece&source=bl&ots=L4ZEqKXVyO&sig=rG5P9InCyvDRbSisOOmZzOCW8_A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TL5dT9DzK5OA8gPj7JiFDw&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false)* is a person who speaks on behalf of another person, often used in a derogatory fashion.  John Galt, for instance, who monologues on the subject at extreme length could be considered a mouthpiece for Ayn Rand's philosophy of Objectivism.

There's also the possibly less apt *raisonneur*, which Lewis Turco defines as

> a "chorus character," one who performs the function of a Greek chorus in that he or she comments on the action of play, sometimes speaking as a *surrogate* (*stand-in*, *mouthpiece*) for the author and acting like the omniscient or ironicalnarrator of a Victorian novel

which also gives *surrogate* and *stand-in* as alternatives.

Comment: While matching what I was looking very precisely, that seems to be an *informal* term, based on dictionary definition. Is there some sort of "official" literary criticism acknowledgement that this is indeed the standard term used for such characters?

Comment: Added a link to the Google Books version of Lewis Turco's "The Book of Literary Terms".

Comment: A similar term would be a didact, that is, a character whose views are intended to be didactic. John Galt is a perfect example of a didact.